# Overlay a page over another page with opacity in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i need help on creating something similar to the image below.
i want to be able to make my current view overlay a view with some blur effect on it[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMH1i.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could user [OverLay](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html) & [backdrop filter.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html) 
Like in the example :

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverLayIssue extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Overlay.of(context).insert(_getEntry(context));
    },
  ),
  body: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('0' * 10000),
    ],
  ),
);
}

OverlayEntry _getEntry(context) {
OverlayEntry entry;

entry = OverlayEntry(
  opaque: false,
  maintainState: true,
  builder: (_) => Positioned(
    left: 100,
    bottom: 100,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: BackdropFilter(
      filter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(
        sigmaX: 2,
        sigmaY: 2,
      ),
      child: Material(
        type: MaterialType.transparency,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text('Hello world'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: () => entry.remove())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
return entry;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const OverlayApp());
}

class OverlayApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const OverlayApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: OverlayExample(),
    );
  }
}

class OverlayExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverlayExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<OverlayExample> createState() => _OverlayExampleState();
}

class _OverlayExampleState extends State<OverlayExample> {
  OverlayEntry? overlayEntry;

  void creteOverlay() {
    removeOverly();

    assert(overlayEntry == null);

    overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(
            sigmaX: 3,
            sigmaY: 3,
          ),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  removeOverly();
                },
                child: const Text('Remove Overlay'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    Overlay.of(context, debugRequiredFor: widget)!.insert(overlayEntry!);
  }

  void removeOverly() {
    overlayEntry?.remove();
    overlayEntry = null;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    removeOverly();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Overlay Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Overlay Test App',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                creteOverlay();
              },
              child: const Text('Show overlay'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                removeOverly();
              },
              child:
                  const Text('Remove overlay - cannot remove with this button'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: working, just fix name error in `removeOverly()`=>`removeOverlay()` and `creteOverlay()`=>`createOverlay()`